# What is UIApplicationLinkedOnOrAfter, and why is it killing my App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I start up my app for debugging, and as far as I can tell, it just barely gets into UIApplicationMain when I get an access error inside of UIApplicationLinkedOnOrAfter.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffc)

I'm on Xcode Version 4.6.2 (4H1003)

Additional info: Fails on the 6.1 simulator, but not the 6.0 simulator.
Aaaaand works on the iPad running iOS 6.1.3.

Comment: Did you try a project clean and delete the app from simulator/device ?

Comment: is it a web app / phonegap or native?

Comment: I ran a clean pretty much first thing. Lemme see if deleting from the sim will help...

Nope.

Answer (score 1):

That function used by apple looks at the date of the UIKit library linked against apparently
NOT the date you linked but the date of the UIKit used... I don't fully get it either I am afraid.

src: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3854388

Comment: Wow, but that guy had his particular problem over a year ago. Hmm.

Comment: I wrote to him. Perhaps he will have a clue.

Comment: Huh. I picked the iPhone 6.0 simulator, instead of the 6.1, and now my code works, (meaning the errors are now my fault).

Comment: Hey, just to make things really fun, it stopped working for the 6.1 simulator. Fortunately it still works with the device.